# Converge annulus of Log of Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex function $f(z)=\frac{U(z)}{V(z)}$ that converges to a Laurent series for over some annulus $r<|z|<R$, where $0<r<R$. Here, $V(z)=1-z^{-1}$ and $U(z)$ is a function such that is analytic inside the unit circle, and $U(1)=0$. For instance, $U(z)=1-0.7z^{-1}-0.3z$.

I'm interested in determining the Laurent series $g(z)=\ln f(z)$. What is the corresponding annulus for $f(z)$?

Comment: What are $U$ and $V$? If $f(z)=z$ then there is no analytic branch of $\ln f(z)$ on the annulus, so you have to tell us how you are defining $\ln (f(z))$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for the comment. I have edited my post appropriately.